# php mysql many to many relationship query result display

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just wondering if you can help me organize the query result from many to many relationship, below are other details.

[image]
here is my query:

`SELECT rt.room_title as rm_name, amn.amnty_title 
FROM amenities_tbl AS amn
LEFT JOIN room_am_link AS ral ON amn.amnty_id = ral.am_id
LEFT JOIN rooms_tbl AS rt ON ral.rm_id = rt.room_id;`

and here is my foreach loop on the query result (codeigniter):

```
<?php foreach($result as $row){?>
<tr>
<td><?php  echo $row['rm_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['am_title']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

the display result is show below,
[image]

but what i want the display to be is like this image below, the room title is not repeated:
[image]

i'm sorry if my questions is very long, i just want it to be clear as much as possible.
thank you and hope you can help me guys.

Comment: You probably need an order by, but other than that, this has little to do with mysql.  Use logic to  only display the room name if the room changes, pretty  basic coding.

Comment: adding order by will only just arrange it alphabetically.

Comment: Yes, and you clearly want it ordered by room name.

Comment: No Sir, i want the room title to be displayed only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple way of doing this is to have a variable, that will keep value of the item from the first column, then in loop, you are displaying it only if value will change, eg.:

```php
<?php 
   $first_col = NULL;

   foreach($result as $row){ ?>
     <tr>
       <td><?php
             if ($first_col != $row['rm_name']) {
               echo $row['rm_name'];
               $first_col = $row['rm_name'];
             } else {
               echo "&nbsp;";
             }; ?>
      </td>
      <td><?php echo $row['am_title']; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

of course, your data should be sorted by this first column - you need to add `ORDER BY` to your SQL.

Comment: Thank You Sir, Appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi Can you please replace with below php code these will help you

<?php 
$titleArray = array();
foreach($result as $row){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php 
$searchVal = array_search($row['rm_name'], $titleArray); 
if($searchVal !== false){
    echo '';
} else {
    $titleArray[] = $row['rm_name'];
    echo $row['rm_name']; 
}
?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['am_title']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```